# converting rows to one column sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i am using the following query to convert rows to column

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT NAME + ',' FROM TABLE1
FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'') AS [ACCOUNT NAMES]
```

the table have the follwing data

```
NAME 
-------------------
GURPREET & CO.
SIMRAN TRADERS
LABOUR & WELFARE
-------------------
```

i want the output like

> GURPREET & CO., SIMRAN TRADERS, LABOUR & WELFARE,

but the sql given the output

> GURPREET &amp CO., SIMRAN TRADERS, LABOUR &amp WELFARE,

how can i remove &amp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're keeping the final comma in your example, you don't need the STUFF, especially if you're using it with parameters `,1,0,''` which is a no-op.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT NAME + ','
       FROM TABLE1
        FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS [ACCOUNT NAMES]
```

If you **did** want to remove the last comma, then it should be like this:

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + NAME
       FROM TABLE1
        FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS [ACCOUNT NAMES]
```

Note: The problem is that you're using a common pattern that is almost as old as the internet, which did not account for XML entitisation.  Using the `FOR XML TYPE` specifier keeps the original text when extracted again via `.value, varchar(max)`.